# How to create an identity column not being a primary key with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How do I create an identity column in SQLAlchemy, auto-incrementing itself and not being the primary key?

I'm using Postgres.

Comment: which database?

Comment: I'm using postgreSql

Comment: Are you sure postgresql support auto-increment columns that are **not** primary? I know it's **not possible** in mysql for example.

Comment: postgresql support sequences, and they don't need to be linked to primary keys

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
table_sequence = Sequence('table_id_seq', start=1)

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    id = Column(Integer, table_sequence, server_default=table_sequence.next_value())
```

Comment: I get this error when creating the sequence: TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Answer (score 0):

Since PostgreSQL 10.0 you can use an [identity column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#identity-ddl) for this (and for a primary key).

For example this code:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=True)

tbl = sa.Table(
        't40959264',
        sa.MetaData(),
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, sa.Identity(always=True), primary_key=True),
        sa.Column('col', sa.Integer, sa.Identity(always=True, start=100, increment=10)),
        )
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), [{}] * 3)
    conn.commit()
    for row in conn.execute(sa.select(tbl)).mappings():
        print(row)
```

generates this DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t40959264 (
        id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
        col INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT BY 10 START WITH 100), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and this output:

```
{'id': 1, 'col': 100}
{'id': 2, 'col': 110}
{'id': 3, 'col': 120}
```